# redirect subfolder , content and files to specific url link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect folder , content and files to **specific** url link

For example

I want to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/
http://www.example.com/folder1/anyfolder
http://www.example.com/folder1/anyfile.anyextension
```

To

```
http://www.example.com/folder2/file.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder1/ /folder2/anyfile.anyextension [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: sorry but i am trying to redirect all folders and files extenstions from /folder1 to /folder2/file.html and file.html is static name not randem and the asterisk * means all names in folders and files

Comment: ok see edited answer as per your changed question. Yes indeed `*` in your question means `.*` in regex

Comment: i tried this code when i go to folder1/ it redirect me to folder2 not folder2/file.html and when i go to folder1/file it gives me error 404 not found

Comment: Are you sure you placed it in `/folder1/.htaccess`? Are there more rules in that .htaccess?

Comment: it's only the code you post , but the folder2 have .htaccess codes . you can review it in this link http://pastebin.centos.org/12946/

Comment: What is the original URL you enter in your browser? Is it `http://www.example.com/folder1/file.html`? Do you want URL to change in browser or just an internal rewrite?

Comment: the original URL is http://www.example.com/folder1/file.html there is no parent directory than folder1 . and yes i want URL to change in browser and

Comment: unfortunately still not working but i changed the /folder2/file.html to full url link , it's works when i visit /folder1 . but it gives me 404 not found when i go to any link inside folder1 like folder1/file.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62786/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ilinux85).